# Csla.resources.dll could not be found

Tags: localization, csla

Localization is required in one of the project.
By default, csla is built for en-US
for other cultures it generates satellite assemblies placed in folders something like
ar/Csla.resources.dll
bs/Csla.resources.dll
etc

I've tried to to put Csla.resources.dll for (for example  "ar") in to my some local dll store. Then refereneced it in my project. It successfully copied into BIN directory of my application next to "csla.dll".
But, when I run the application the error messages for broken business rules appear only in  pure English.
after experiments I've found that if I create (manually) a folder "ar" in my "bin" directory and then copy there Csla.resources.dll then everything is OK  and I see localized error messages.

Is there a way not to manually create directory, copy Csla.resources.dll etc but instead just to reference Csla.resources.dll in project and all that creation/coping will do automatically?

Comment: in post-build events for project I added these commands: 
`rmdir  $(TargetDir)ar`
`mkdir  $(TargetDir)ar`
`move  $(TargetDir)Csla.resources.ar.dll $(TargetDir)ar\Csla.resources.dll`

But is it there more elegant and more correct way to use the specific localization for csla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the `Csla` NuGet package does not include localized resources, so I think your solution is the best workaround.

I have created a backlog item to add the localized resources in a future release.

https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/issues/1413

Comment: it would be great!